# Typhoon lazy injection in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, dependency-injection, lazy-initialization, typhoon

While trying and playing around with Typhoon DI, I realized that LazySingleton scope is not working as expected meaning lazy properties are injected even before they are used. Being more concrete I created a TyphoonAssembly as follow :

```
public class AppAssembly : TyphoonAssembly {

    public dynamic func knight() -> AnyObject{

        return TyphoonDefinition.withClass(Knight.self){
            (definition) in

            definition.injectProperty("name", with: "Dragon")

            definition.injectProperty("horse")

            definition.scope = TyphoonScope.LazySingleton

        }
    }

    public dynamic func horse() -> AnyObject{

        return TyphoonDefinition.withClass(Horse.self){
            (definition) in

            definition.injectProperty("color", with: "red")

            definition.scope = TyphoonScope.LazySingleton
        }
    }

}
```

where Knight is NSObject and has `validateProperties` function

```
class Knight:NSObject {

    var name:String?
    var horse: Horse?

    func validateProperties(){

        if name != nil{

            println("Name not nil")
        }

        if horse != nil{

            println("Horse not nil")
        }
    }
}
```

After activating assembly and getting knight from it, calling `validateProperties` function always print Name not nil and Horse not nil even these properties are never used in my code. Am I missing something here or simply lazy injection does not work same as Swift lazy stored properties do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your interpretation of the term lazy singleton makes sense, but its not the correct one. `TyphoonScopeLazySingleton` means that Typhoon won't instantiate the whole object until its asked for. Once asked for all properties will be injected. There's no proxying to inject on demand - if you're interested in such a feature, would you mind raising an issue for us in Github?

You're right that such a feature would only work in Swift if the class extended `NSObject` and the properties were types compatible with Objective-C, as "pure" Swift uses C++ style static dispatch, and therefore runtime method interception/proxying is not possible.

Here's the [user guide for Typhoon scopes](https://github.com/appsquickly/Typhoon/wiki/Scopes).